# WSO2 on Docker not accessible with HTTPS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I followed instructions at https://wso2.com/integration/install/docker/get-started/. When I try to access
https://localhost:9743/dashboard
as indicated, I get confronted right away with the HTTPS issue in edge, chrome and firefox. After entering login and password (admin, admin), I get a dialogbox as follows

[image]

I click on the link I get unable to connect in all browsers

[image]

I downloaded the pem certificate in Firefox, added it to trusted store but it did not help
Not sure what is needed to be done

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the MI docker container as follows where it exposes port 9164.

```
docker run -it -p 8253:8253 -p 8290:8290 -p 9164:9164 docker.wso2.com/wso2mi:1.2.0
```

Then you can start the MI Dashboard container as below.

```
docker run -it -p 9743:9743 wso2/wso2mi-dashboard:1.2.0
```

When you are logging from the MI dashboard server, it calls the MI instance to authenticate the user.

Comment: Thanks, yes it worked now with adding this

Comment: Thanks, yes I can access now